# Hidden zip and unzip folders using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Below is my script

zIP Script

```
wvar1 = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\Dumps"
wvar2 = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\Dumps.zip"
set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ArchiveFolder wvar2, wvar1

Sub ArchiveFolder (zipFile, sFolder)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

        Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _
                 .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
            WScript.Sleep 1000 
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

unzIP Script

```
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
ZipFile = "" & strFolder & "\Scripts\Dumper_AV.zip" & ""
ExtractTo= var1
 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sourceFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ZipFile)
destFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ExtractTo)
 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(sourceFile).Items()
objShell.NameSpace(destFolder).copyHere FilesInZip, 16
Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set FilesInZip = Nothing
```

But i wanted it hidden to zip silently, but it opens up a progress box displaying compressing same with my unzip script.
is there a way to hide it.

As per docs vOptions 4 to hide progress is being ignored

***Solved Hidden Unzipping But solution required for hidden Zipping***

Comment: If you want to try with a powershell script into a vbscript using the cmdlet `Compress-Archive`  : [Compress_Archive_by_Extension.vbs](https://pastebin.com/w8xqBszC)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Solution**

***For UNZIP Script Only***

**Trick 1** : Use Vbsedit to compile vbscript to exe and it will execute silently

**Trick 2** : .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items, &H4

**Note:** As per docs  .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items, 4 doesn't work. vOption variable 4 need to be converrted to Hex string &H4 to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Note the second parameter to `CopyHere`.

```
 .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items, 4
```

From the docs

> ```
> Folder.CopyHere(
>   vItem,
>   [ vOptions ]
> )
> ```
>
> ...
>
> (4)
>
> Do not display a progress dialog box.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere

Comment: vOptions 4 is being ignored.